# Is there a way to filter files via variable string in a filename?

Tags: python

I am trying to filter all files with a common pattern. Why cant I put a variable pattern to filter.

```
listOfFiles = os.listdir('.')
casenr = str(nr)
pattern = "*"+str(nr)+"_*.state"
for entry in listOfFiles:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, pattern):
        statefile = entry
print(statefile)
```

I expect to find a file named

init_8_abc.txt

Comment: You can use regex for this task. Which pattern do you wanna search for?

Comment: just use `glob.glob`

Comment: The Pattern would be like this: pattern = "*"+str(nr)+"_*.state"

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use `glob`? Following your example you could do:

```
import glob

pattern = f'/path/to/directory/with/files/*{str(nr)}_*.state'
files = glob.glob(pattern)

for file in files:
    doSomething(file)
```

`glob` allows for searching files with specific pattern using `*` wildcards (you can use wildcards in any part of the pattern, e.g. to search in multiple subdirectories). See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).
Also, note that the use of f-strings is only supported by python >3.6.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Your code will only print the *last* match, however, since each time it finds a match it overwrites `statefile` with that match. Make statefile be a list and do `statefile.append(entry)` and you should get a list of all matches.

This works for me:

```py
import os, fnmatch
listOfFiles = os.listdir('.')
pattern = "*"+"1"+"*"
statefile = []
for entry in listOfFiles:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, pattern):
        statefile.append(entry)
print(statefile)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to build some none-trivial filters for list of filenames:

```
import re

filenames = [
    "_filename_example1",
    "_filename_examples",
    "filename_example2",
    "_filename_example_",
]

regex = re.compile("_.*\d")
selected = filter(regex.match, filenames)
for s in selected:
    print(s)
```

Given example displays only **_filename_example1** because it starts with *_* and ends with *number*.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import re

listOfFiles = os.listdir('.')
nr = '<wherever this is coming from>'

for filename in listOfFiles:
    foundFiles = re.findall('^[\\w]+_' + str(nr) + '_[\\w.]+', filename)

print(foundFiles)
```